# ccTouchBegan Function Is Executing If-Statement Incorrectly

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm currently attempting to read and store touches on an iOS device using Cocos2D. My method is to handle each touch (multitouch is enabled) individually in the ccTouchBegan, ccTouchMoved, ccTouchCanceled, and ccTouchEnded functions.

The ivars of importance are:

- activeTouches (int which is incremented or decremented when a new valid touch (valid meaning not near the joystick) is received).
- acceptingGestures (bool which is used to ignore any new touches)
- gestureTimer (float which is continuously incremented by ccTime in the update function. when it is above some threshold, acceptingGestures is set to FALSE)

Here is my code:

```
-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation];
    touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];

    //check to see if touch is near joystick to prevent accidental gestures. may want to consider increasing the 'deadzone' value
    if(abs(self.joystickLocation.x - touchLocation.x) <= 35 && abs(self.joystickLocation.y - touchLocation.y) <= 35)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    if(self.activeTouches == 0)
    {
        [self setGestureTimerEnable:TRUE];
        [self setGestureTimer:0.0f];
    }

    if(self.acceptingGestures == TRUE);
    {
        if (self.firstTouch == nil)
        {
            self.firstTouch = touch;
            self.activeTouches++;
            return YES;
        }
        else if (self.secondTouch == nil)
        {
            self.secondTouch = touch;
            self.activeTouches++;
            return YES;
        }
    }

    CCLOG(@"touched: %f, %f\n",touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y);
    return NO;
}
```

I'm experiencing a weird problem in the ccTouchBegan function. My test scenario, using the emulator, is I have 1 touch recognized by the software and then gestureTimer is running. After x time, the gestureTimer surpasses a threshold and sets acceptingGestures to FALSE. I then apply a 2nd touch to the screen, and the code accepts the touch and increments the activeTouches variable! It shouldn't be able to do that!

I set a breakpoint using the debugger and tried to capture this weird event. Even though acceptingGestures is FALSE (the acceptingGestures expression at the breakpoint is indeed FALSE), the code still makes it through the If-Statement! In the screenshot attached, notice the acceptingGestures is FALSE.

I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

[image: Debugger screenshot. Notice the acceptingGestures is FALSE.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my problem. I had a semicolon after my if-statement! Womp womp. I wanted to delete my post but maybe someone will see my gesture code and gain something from it?

Comment: 'xept one thing: in objc it's BOOL not bool and YES/NO instead of TRUE/FALSE ;)